# Programación de un cajero automático en C

Tags: c

¡Buenas! Soy nuevo en Stack, he tenido que venir ya que tengo un problema. Veamos, estoy realizando un cajero automático en C (repositorio en https://github.com/Vera0011/C/tree/master/ATM%20(Cajero)/Funciones ). El problema es que estoy usando una función (la del archivo fileEdit.c) para editar el archivo que contiene el dinero de cierto usuario. El problema es que cuando llamo a esa función (dentro de la del archivo addMoney.c), el programa crashea. ¿Alguien sabría por qué?

Archivo addMoney:

```
// DONE BY VERA

// Librerías
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void menu(void);
void fileCreate(void);
void options(void);
int verif(char* x);
char* values(char* a);
void fileEdit(char* b);
void seeMoney(void);

// Función para añadir dinero a la cuenta

void addMoney(void)
{
    char buff[1000];
    char* amount;

    printf("\n*** AGREGAR DINERO A LA CUENTA ***\nPor favor, ingresa el importe que deseas abonar a tu cuenta bancaria:\n*************\n");
    scanf("%s", amount);

    int review = verif(amount);
    if (review == 1)
    {
        FILE* file;

        file = fopen("bankAccount.txt", "r");

        if (file == 0 || file == NULL)
        {
            printf("\n*** ERROR ***\nNo hemos encontrado ningun archivo con tu cuenta bancaria. Se ha creado uno.\n*************\n");
            fileCreate();
            menu();
        }
        else
        {
            int i = 0;


            while (fscanf(file, "%[^\n]", buff) != EOF && i < 4)
            {
                fgetc(file);
                i++;
            }

            fclose(file);

            char* a = values(buff);

            int y = atoi(a) + atoi(amount);

            char* q = "";
            char* x = itoa(y, q, 10);

            fileEdit(x);
            
            options();

        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n*** LOS VALORES INTRODUCIDOS SON INCORRECTOS, VUELVE A INTENTARLO ***\n***************\n");
        addMoney();
    }
}
```

Archivo fileEdit:

```
// DONE BY VERA
 
// Librerías
#include <stdio.h>
 
// Función para añadir un string a otro
 
char *addString(char* a, char *money)
{
    int i = 0;
    int x = 0;
    while (money[x] != '\0')
    {
        x++;
    }
    while (a[i] != '\0')
    {
        money[x + i] = a[i];
        i++;
    }
    money[x + i] = '\0';
    return (money);
}
 
// Función para crear un nuevo archivo
 
void fileEdit(char *b)
{
    char name[] = "name = Vera";
    char pin[] = "pin = 1234";
    char money[] = "account = ";
    char* x = addString(b, money);
    FILE* file;
 
    file = fopen("bankAccount.txt", "w+");
 
    fprintf(file, "%s\n", name);
 
    fprintf(file, "%s\n", pin);
 
    fprintf(file, "%s", x);
 
    fclose(file);
 
    return;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Se crashea porque en ningún momento invocas el archivo `fileEdit.c` desde `addMoney.c`, si ambos se encuentran en el mismo directorio llama a `fileEdit.c` así(esto va junto a los demas `#include`:

```
 #include "fileEdit.c"
```

[Aquí](https://riptutorial.com/c/example/3250/calling-a-function-from-another-c-file) hay una explicación (en ingles) y un ejemplo de como funciona la invocación de archivos en C con un header

Comment: Pero poniendo solamente `void fileEdit(char* b);` en el archivo `addMoney.c`, no funcionaría? Siempre me ha servido eso

Comment: `void fileEdit(char* b);` solo le dice al compilador que es seguro que en lo que resta del archivo(o en una invocación) se encuentra una función llamada fileEdit, cosa que no ocurre, sinceramente no se de que forma es que lograbas llamar funciones de un archivo C a otro sin invocar el propio archivo o un header que le apunte (tal vez alguna configuración de compilador que usaste(?) porque normalmente esto no deberia funcionar (gracias a dios que no es así...)

Comment: Pues la verdad es que no me ha servidor, sigue crasehando todavía. No se cambia el archivo ni salta el menú de opciones (edité todo el programa para que se adecuara a los headers, pero nada)

Comment: Nada que agregar, sigues diciendo que se crashea tu programa pero no muestras error log ni nada para verificar que el problema que estoy tratando de solucionar (error de invocación ) fue solucionado. Cualquier otro error de código requiere una pregunta aparte.

Comment: Ese es el problema, no salta ningún error ni nada en los logs, pero bueno, gracias.